# AWS EC2 test server

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to do some test on a server we have on Amazon Cloud, I found some pretty good docs regarding the process to clone the prod server like this one:
http://www.misterjensen.com/site/how-to-clone-an-amazon-web-services-ec2-instance/

But my main concern is that if I clone the server and boot it my app will start to mess with my other prod servers. One way could be to quickly log on the server to stop the app but it is not very clean..

Is there any other way to avoid the clone server to reach other server ? Unfortunately it is not like my VMware infra where I can simply disconnect the network and use the console to connect..

Thanks

Comment: How would your application mess with other production servers? Is it a worker reading from SQS?

Comment: We use that server for web apps that regularly connect to server in our own datacenter and other cloud services in order to sync or update data. So when the app start it will automatically start to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

If your application connects with other servers that are in the **same network (VPC),** then the simplest solution is to launch your 'cloned' server in a different [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/ExerciseOverview.html).

If your application connects with **AWS services** such as Amazon S3 and Amazon SQS, then you will need to give your server **different credentials** that **do not** have access to the production resources of these services. Credentials are assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance via the **Role** parameter at startup, so created a different Role (without access to production resources) and assign it when launching the 'clone'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it is a valid solution. But you lead me to another solution that could be easier than using another VPC. Using security group to block the traffic I don't want http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html     I will take a closer look tomorrow.